# Do redundant generic type parameters affect performance?

Tags: c#, performance, generics, methods

I have a method, with generics that are never used:

```
public struct dummy {}

public static int DoSomething<T1,T2,T3>(int someParameter, T1 a1 = default, T2 a2 = default, T3 a3 = default)
{
    someParameter += 4;
    return someParameter;
}

public static void Main()
{
    var r1 = DoSomething<decimal, decimal, decimal>(5);
    var r2 = DoSomething<dummy, dummy, dummy>(12);
}
```

Are there any performance issues with any of the `DoSomething` method calls?

Comment: Why do you have unused generic parameters? Why don't you simply remove them? I think you end up with code size bloat because of how generics work with structs in the IL

Comment: I have a method that have 12 generics, the method will be called for others using 1,2,3,4... generics, I guess you can't discard generics in C# so I need to know if affect the performance, if does I need to copy & paste the method for each generic.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: But... You're not using them. You need to expand your example to show how they're *really* called and what purpose the generic parameters actually serve. Also fix your examples. `DoSomething` returns `void` so it can't assign to `r1` and `r2`. Also, `+=` on a byval `int` *alone* does nothing if that's your entire method. Show some real code if you want some real help. It's still not clear why you need/have unused generic parameters. Your explanation makes no sense to me.

Comment: But to answer your question, no there's not going to be a performance impact (if you're talking about speed). If there is, you're micro-optimizing at this point and the first rule of optimization is almost always "don't".

Comment: Thanks for the correction. This is the method that will be called: https://pastebin.com/71KVvBLy

Comment: If I was reviewing this for performance. I would  be more concerned that your method is creating a delegate and throwing it away. Seems like an unnecessary step and you could just pass all arguments by calling Invoke on the methodinfo. If you were concerned about performance you'd be caching the delegates to get the performance benefit out of creating them.

Comment: Why don't you just have 9 different `InvokeMethodInternal` implementations, from no generics to `T1` to `T1...T8`? There you would avoid the switch and the arguments count

Comment: @mikez caching the delegates is something I'm taking in account, but is not added yet.

Comment: Its fairly common to have overloads that vary primarily in generic arity; see [Tuple.Create](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,8e2a2c5c7e686c09).

Comment: Also case 1 has a bug. The obj argument is missing.

Comment: @mikez Yes, but that looks clean, I was trying to have only 1 method because is easy to maintain, but well, will be just few copy & paste.

Answer (score 3):

The method will get JITed once for any reference types - this code can then be re-used for any future reference type passed as a generic type parameter.

For value types the method will have to be JITed again for each new type.

So there will be a small performance cost the first time you pass a reference type and then again for each different value type.

So to answer your specific question it doesn't matter whether or not you use the type parameters - you'll incur a small cost each time you call the method with a new value type. If you got rid of the generic parameters altogether the method would only ever be JITed once.

Answer (score 1):

In general, other than the minor cost of JITting for each value type the generic is used with (as describe by @RagtimeWilly), generics are usually more performant than the equivalent pre-generic code (that would usually use object parameters for polymorphism).  You don't pay the cost of boxing and un-boxing value types into boxed objects with generics.

But, other than keeping "hey, generics aren't just cool, they're fast" in the back of your head, this is pretty useless information in the real world.

If you are thinking like this, you are doing premature micro-optimization.  Think about writing good code.  Use the tools at your finger-tips (like generics, lamdas, etc.) in the correct way - after figuring out what that way is.

Answer (score 0):

There is no recognizable (even at large scales) impact from generics in methods.

I think the greater problem, though, is the fact that you have unused generics in the first place.